# SQL GROUP BY two columns but grouping one by one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have simple table that keeps all the data when users login.

`id` | `user_id` | `ip` | `date`

As you know I have users logging from many IPs and users logging from one IP.
I want to get those that log from one IP. So I need to GROUP BY `ip` but also need the count of UNIQUE `user_id` that has data with this IP. And I want to order it by the most users logging from the same IP.

The problem is GROUP BY groups by both ip and user_id. I guess I need insite query, but I have no idea how to do it.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`id`) 
FROM `TABLE` 
GROUP BY `ip`, `user_id` 
ORDER BY COUNT(`id`)
```

Any idea? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [the `DISTINCT` keyword](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-distinct.php):

```
SELECT IP, COUNT(DISTINCT user_ID) AS NumberOfUsers
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY IP
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_ID) > 1 -- this will filter to show only IPs with multiple users
ORDER BY NumberOfUsers DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as unique_ip_count
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ip)=1
```